# TFS - Deleted a folder from File System - Now Checkin Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Apologies if this has been asked before - I just cannot track down the answer.

I have done something wrong and broken my TFS

I was adding a new project to my solution and accidentally added it as a Visual Basic project.

I wanted a C# project.

In Solution Explorer, I right clicked the project and selected "Remove (Del)"

Then, and this is what I think I have done wrong..

I then went to my file system and deleted the directory.

I then went back to VS and added a project of the same name in the same directory but this time in C#.

I then went to check in my solution and it's complaining it cannot find all the .vb files that I manually deleted from my disk.

I know I can manually exclude them, but I keep ending up with a long list of "excluded files" which never seem to go.

What can I do to repair this please and stop TFS thinking these files need to be checked in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GO in the Source code explorer of TFS, and commit the deleted files, or fix any other weird things.

The Solution, or projects contain the files that have to be used. Visual Studio shows only the files that are in the projects. If you delete a project, and have pending changes. The project is removed from the solution, but the files have still pending changes even if they are not shown anymore.

So when you create a new project in the same directory, you could have some problems to fix first in the Source code explorer of TFS